# Instagram JSON TypeError: Cannot read property "text" from undefined

Tags: google-apps-script, instagram

I'm trying to build analytics with Google Sheet for Instagram, but I keep getting errors when I want to return the caption text from an image url.

I've tried different variations of my code, but it's always the same issue. Either my result comes back (in the output) as "undefined", or it just throws errors.

```
    function MultipleHashtags() {
  //Set up multiple sheets and instagram accounts
var hashtagArray = ["fitness", "fashion"];

  for(var i = 0; i < hashtagArray.length; i++) { grabData( hashtagArray[i]); };
//Grab data from TOP 9 posts
  function grabData(tag) {


  var url = "https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/"+tag+"/?__a=1";
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();

    for(var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
      var hashtag = JSON.parse(response).graphql.hashtag.name;
      var postOwner = JSON.parse(response).graphql.hashtag.edge_hashtag_to_top_posts.edges[i].node.owner.id;
      var shortCode = JSON.parse(response).graphql.hashtag.edge_hashtag_to_top_posts.edges[i].node.shortcode;
      var URL = "https://www.instagram.com/p/"+shortCode;
      var isVideo = JSON.parse(response).graphql.hashtag.edge_hashtag_to_top_posts.edges[i].node.is_video;
      var PostComments = JSON.parse(response).graphql.hashtag.edge_hashtag_to_top_posts.edges[i].node.edge_media_to_comment.count;
      var PostLikes = JSON.parse(response).graphql.hashtag.edge_hashtag_to_top_posts.edges[i].node.edge_liked_by.count;      
      var caption = JSON.parse(response).graphql.hashtag.edge_hashtag_to_top_posts.edges[i].node.edge_media_to_caption.edges.node.text;
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2"); 
      sheet.appendRow([Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "yyyy-MM-dd"), hashtag, postOwner, shortCode, URL, isVideo, PostComments, PostLikes, caption])
      var range = sheet.getRange("A2:H")
      range.sort([{column: 1, ascending: false}]);
      Utilities.sleep(200);; 
    }  
  } 
};
```

Might not be the best code yet, but i'm still learning :). Any help would be appreciated.

What this script does is read the dump that's behind this URL:
https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/fashion/?__a=1

for instance:

```
"graphql":{"hashtag":{"name":"fashion","is_top_media_only":false,"profile_pic_url":"https://scontent-bru2-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/3919f4813f1759cd589c9e256fafa05b/5B584579/t51.2885-15/s150x150/e35/c0.135.1080.1080/29717343_617997658538341_2606017788199829504_n.jpg","edge_hashtag_to_media":{"count":494984995,"page_info":{"has_next_page":true,"end_cursor":"AQBYZqz6Bc4vBlwhzRuhZm1NQSk7HQmHsJ9ZdMzanB-4UAH9rfDCjuWq-iqx5iEEaT0pPeJ_2aydWn_ZToa_aR5wt2ww743GTMbvIfx1lEAlpQ"},"edges":[{"node":{"comments_disabled":false,"id":"1750034539685082052","edge_media_to_caption":{"edges":[{"node":{"text":"NEW | Our new webshop is online!\n\nwww.ivan-online.nl\nFrom now on you can order your shawl easily online. A special gift for yourself, or for someone else. A warm shawl with a warm story.\n\nLet us know what you think about it \ud83d\ude4f \u2014\n\u2014\n#webshop #fashion #shawl #sjaal #cashmere #kasjmir #internetfashion #fashionable #handmade #nepal #fairtrade #springfashion #2018\n#photo"}}]},"shortcode":"BhJXyRKl_PE","edge_media_to_comment":{"count":0},"taken_at_timestamp":1522840395,"dimensions":{"height":720,"width":1080},"display_url":"https://scontent-bru2-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/cbf53cb645805430051bc7b056fb1dbf/5B643AD8/t51.2885-15/e35/29414609_430637507388196_1941728523811028992_n.jpg","edge_liked_by":{"count":0},"edge_media_preview_like":{"count":0},"owner":{"id":"5998662494"},"thumbnail_src":"https://scontent-bru2-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/68d5e9377dee9bfb0165bfa18473b6c6/5B56C8D8/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/c180.0.720.720/29414609_430637507388196_1941728523811028992_n.jpg","thumbnail_resources":[{"src":"https://scontent-bru2-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/e8a4b97569e409822c382ddb3231af00/5B62B69B/t51.2885-15/s150x150/e35/c180.0.720.720/29414609_430637507388196_1941728523811028992_n.jpg","config_width":150,"config_height":150},{"src":"https://scontent-bru2-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/fbc573c382379e29a4b321b1b5e423c3/5B5A190D/t51.2885-15/s240x240/e35/c180.0.720.720/29414609_430637507388196_1941728523811028992_n.jpg","config_width":240,"config_height":240},{"src":"https://scontent-bru2-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/a5b50f4711a8ab1774320c912cb70b7c/5B620CE5/t51.2885-15/s320x320/e35/c180.0.720.720/29414609_430637507388196_1941728523811028992_n.jpg","config_width":320,"config_height":320},{"src":"https://scontent-bru2-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/b27613e12796dfb97803acd4e429c20d/5B5C9FCC/t51.2885-15/s480x480/e35/c180.0.720.720/29414609_430637507388196_1941728523811028992_n.jpg","config_width":480,"config_height":480},{"src":"https://scontent-bru2-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/68d5e9377dee9bfb0165bfa18473b6c6/5B56C8D8/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/c180.0.720.720/29414609_430637507388196_1941728523811028992_n.jpg","config_width":640,"config_height":640}],"is_video":false}}
```

In there is the following line that's of interest:

```
"edge_media_to_caption":{"edges":[{"node":{"text":"NEW | Our new webshop is online!\n\nwww.ivan-online.nl\nFrom now on you can order your shawl easily online. A special gift for yourself, or for someone else. A warm shawl with a warm story.\n\nLet us know what you think about it \ud83d\ude4f \u2014\n\u2014\n#webshop #fashion #shawl #sjaal #cashmere #kasjmir #internetfashion #fashionable #handmade #nepal #fairtrade #springfashion #2018\n#photo"}}]}
```

Which i'm trying to grab with:

```
var caption = JSON.parse(response).graphql.hashtag.edge_hashtag_to_top_posts.edges[i].node.edge_media_to_caption.edges.node.text;
```

And this returns the error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property "text" from undefined

From stackdriver:

> 2018-04-04 14:20:42.316 CEST
>   TypeError: Cannot read property "text" from undefined. at grabData(GrabData:21) at MultipleHashtags(GrabData:5)
>   Expand all | Collapse all {
>    insertId:  "198nrphg1tmmbn6"
>    jsonPayload: {…}
>    labels: {…}
>    logName:  "projects/project-id-1872200188033847311/logs/script.googleapis.com%2Fconsole_logs"
>    receiveTimestamp:  "2018-04-04T12:20:43.328274499Z"
>    resource: {…}
>    severity:  "ERROR"
>    timestamp:  "2018-04-04T12:20:42.316Z"
>   }

Comment: What errors are you getting? Could you provide the value stored in `response`?

Comment: @Diego added some additional info

Comment: I recommend storing the parsed response: `var r = JSON.parse(response);` and logging its contents so you can see what properties are really there: `console.log(r);` (logs to Stackdriver). My guess is a typo/capitalization issue. In Stackdriver, you can easily explore the structure of the passed data - this is not easy to do in the Apps Script `Logger` window.

Comment: @tehhowch added :)

Comment: @ThomasSt no, you only added the error report from Stackdriver. I'm saying you need to log the object you're working with so you can understand its structure and why your access failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you're getting the errors is because you're trying to access an object property that doesn't exist. Unfortunately, this is heavily nested data, so you'll need to do a lot of checks here. There are multiple ways to do this, but I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631001/test-for-existence-of-nested-javascript-object-key) as a guide.

In the code below, I broke out your `grabData()` function as I'm personally not a fan of nested functions.

```
function MultipleHashtags() {
  //Set up multiple sheets and instagram accounts
  var hashtagArray = ["fitness", "fashion"];
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2"); 
  var range = sheet.getRange("A2:H")
  range.sort([{column: 1, ascending: false}]);
  Utilities.sleep(200);;
  for(var i = 0; i < hashtagArray.length; i++) {
    var data = grabData(hashtagArray[i]); 
    sheet.appendRow([Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "yyyy-MM-dd"), data.hashtag, data.postOwner, data.shortCode, data.URL, data.isVideo, data.PostComments, data.PostLikes, data.caption]);
  }
}

//Grab data from TOP 9 posts
function grabData(tag) {
  var url = "https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/"+tag+"/?__a=1";
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
  var responseObject = JSON.parse(response);
  var hashtagData = responseObject.graphql.hashtag;
  var data = {};
  for(var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    var hashtag = hashtagData.name;
    if (checkNested(hashtagData, "edge_hashtag_to_top_posts", "edges")) {
      var edge = hashtagData.edge_hashtag_to_top_posts.edges[i];
      if (checkNested(edge, "node")) {
        var node = edge.node;
        var postOwner = checkNested(node, "owner", "id") ? node.owner.id : "";
        var shortCode = checkNested(node, "shortcode") ? node.shortcode : "";
        var URL = "https://www.instagram.com/p/"+shortCode;
        var isVideo = checkNested(node, "is_video") ? node.is_video : "";
        var PostComments = checkNested(node, "edge_media_to_comment", "count") ? node.edge_media_to_comment.count : "";
        var PostLikes = checkNested(node, "edge_liked_by", "count") ? node.edge_liked_by.count : "";
        var caption = "";
        if (checkNested(node, "edge_media_to_caption", "edges")) {
          var captions = node.edge_media_to_caption.edges[0];
          caption = checkNested(captions, "node", "text") ? captions.node.text : "";
        }
      }
    }
    data = {
      "hashtag": hashtag,
      "postOwner": postOwner,
      "shortCode": shortCode,
      "URL": URL,
      "isVideo": isVideo,
      "PostComments": PostComments,
      "PostLikes": PostLikes,
      "caption": caption
    };
  }
  return data;
}

/**
 * Test for existence of nested JavaScript object key
 * Copied from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631001/test-for-existence-of-nested-javascript-object-key
 */
function checkNested(obj /*, level1, level2, ... levelN*/) {
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);

  for (var i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
    if (!obj || !obj.hasOwnProperty(args[i])) {
      return false;
    }
    obj = obj[args[i]];
  }
  return true;
}
```

EDIT: Forgot a major point about your original code. When you were accessing the caption, `var caption = JSON.parse(response).graphql.hashtag.edge_hashtag_to_top_posts.edges[i].node.edge_media_to_caption.edges.node.text;`, the last `edges` is actually an array. In my code, I only selected the first element of that array. You can update as necessary.